# Enforcing property-level authorization in domain objects

Tags: security, rest, authorization, domain-driven-design

I am implementing a RESTful service that has a security model requiring authorization at three levels:

1. **Resource level authorization** - determining whether the user has
   access to the resource (entity) at all.  For example, does the
   current user have permission to view customers in general.  If not,
   then everything stops there.
2. **Instance level authorization** - determining whether the user has
   access to a specific instance of a resource (entity).  Due to
   various rules and the state of the entity, the current user may not
   be granted access to one of more customers within the set of
   customers.  E.g., a customer may be able to view their own information but not the information of another customer.
3. **Property level authorization** - determine which properties the user
   has access to on an instance of the resource (entity).  We have many
   business rules that determine whether a user may see and/or change
   individual properties of a resource (entity).  For example, the
   current user may be able to see the customer's name but not their
   address or phone number as well as able to see and add notes.

Implementing resource-level authorization is straight-forward; however, the other two are not.  I believe the solution for instance-level authorization will reveal itself with a solution to the (harder, imo) property-level authorization question.  The latter issue is complicated by the fact that I need to communicate the authorization decisions, by property, in the response message (ala hypermedia) - in other words, this isn't something I can simply enforce in property setters.

With each request to the service, I must use the current user's information to perform these authorization checks.  In the case of a GET request for either a list of resources or an individual resource, I need to tell the API layer which attributes the current user can see (is visible) and whether the attribute is read-only or editable.  The API layer will then use this information to create the appropriate response message.  For instance, any property that is not visible will not be included in the message.  Read-only properties will be flagged so the client application can render the property in the appropriate state for the user.

Solutions like application services, aspects, etc. work great for resource-level authorization and can even be used for instance-level checks, but I am stuck determining how best to model my domain so the business rules and checks enforcing the security constraints are included.

NOTE: Keep in mind that this goes way beyond role-based security in that I am getting the final authorization result based on business rules using the current state of the resource and environment (along with verifying access using the permissions granted to the current user via their roles).

**How should I model the domain so I have enforcement of all three types of authorization checks** (in a testable way, with DI, etc)?

Comment: Authorization rules do not really belong in the domain, unless naturally expressed in domain terms. E.g. `deactivate(Manager manager)`. Additionally, DDD is all about real behavior, not CRUD. If you have setters for every individual problem, then DDD is the wrong solution for your domain or you modeled your domain incorrectly. Therefore, rather than looking at protecting data at the property-level for the writes, you should be looking into protecting business operations.

Comment: I agree with you that our domain objects should only be mutable through methods.  My question actually has less to do with changing the object and more to do with how the rules are used to create the appropriate representation of the object.

Comment: For example, if the current user is not permitted to view certain properties of the object based not only on his/her permissions, but on business rules that govern the behavior of the object.  I need to dynamically apply these rules, in conjunction with the user's permissions, to determine the current state of the object not only at the entity level but also at the property/attribute level.

Comment: Trying to make this the responsibility of your domain will be very painful. I'm not sure exactly what kind of business rules needs to be checked in conjunction with the ACL, but perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to first query the objects from the DB that can be viewed by the user in a specific context. Then, for that set of objects, load the related property-level authorizations and apply them as you construct DTOs. If you had no business rules to check in addition, I would have suggested that you do not read from your business objects at all, but directly from result sets.

Comment: I had the same thought about applying the rules when constructing DTOs but am not sure how to go about that.  It's easy to define a policy at the entity level, but how to model doing so at a property level?  I'm almost thinking the properties need to be value types encapsulating the rules, but they would require a reference to the parent entity and accept the current user as a parameter.  I'm looking at the explosion this creates and hesitate to go down this path if a better solution exists.

Comment: No, do not encapsulate properties! That would mean handling the problem in the domain. I think you could solve the problem by having a single generic configurable PropertyAccessSpecification as well as a few specialized specifications/policies for rules that aren't ACL-like (e.g. entity's owner can access all). Then everything can be handled in a generic way.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more details in an answer (can't accept a comment)...

Comment: @SonOfPirate Do you have any reference for the 3 levels (resource, instance, property) of authorization? Or did you come up with them by yourself? Thanks!

Comment: No, I didn't come up with this on my own, this model was a business requirement.  It's been a while, but I believe tools like Dynamics CRM and Saleforce have granular permissions such as this.

Comment: @SonOfPirate I see. Thank you for your response. I'll check on Dynamics CRM and Saleforce.

Answer (score 2):

**Initial Assumptions**

I suppose the following architecture:

```
                                     Stateless Scaling                                          Sharding
                                             .                                                     .
                                             .                                                     .
                                             .                                                     .
                         +=========================================+
                         |  Service Layer                          |
+----------+             |  +-----------+        +---------------+ |                         +------------+
|          |    HTTP     |  |           |        |               | |   Driver, Wire, etc.    |            |
|  Client  | <============> |  RESTful  | <====> |  Data Access  | <=======================> |  Database  |
|          |    JSON     |  |  Service  |  DTO   |     Layer     | |     ORM, Raw, etc.      |            |
|          |             |  |           |        |               | |                         |            |
+----------+             |  +-----------+        +---------------+ |                         +------------+
                         +=========================================+
                                             .                                                     .
                                             .                                                     .
                                             .                                                     .
```

Initially, let us suppose you are authenticating the `Client` with the `Service Layer` and obtain a particular *token*, that encodes the authentication and authorization information in it.

First of all, what I first think of is to process all the requests and then only filter them depending on authorization. This will make the whole thing much simpler and much easier to maintain. However, of course there might be some requests requiring expensive processing, in which case this approach is absolutely not effective. On the other hand, the heavy-load requests will most probably involve resource level access, which as you have stated is easy to organise, and it is possible to detect and authorise in `Service Layer` at `API` or at least `Data Access` levels.

**Further Thoughts**

As for *instance* and *property* level authorization, I will not even try to put it into the `Data Access Layer` and would completely isolate it beyond the API level, i.e. starting from `Data Access Layer` no any layer would even be aware of it. Even if you request a list of *1M* objects and want to emit one or two properties from all objects for that particular client, it would be preferable to fetch the whole objects and then only hide the properties.

Another assumption is that your model is a clear `DTO`, i.e. simply a data container, and all the business logic is implemented in the `Service Layer`, particularly `API` level. And say you pass the data across HTTP encoded as `JSON`. So anyway, somewhere in front of the `API` layer, you are going to have a small serialization stage, to transform your model into `JSON`. So this stage is where I think is the ideal place to put the instance and property authorization.

**Suggestion**

If it comes to the property level authorization, I think there is no reasonable way to isolate the model from security logic. Be it a *rule-based, role-based or whatever-based* authorisation, the process is going to be verified upon a piece of value from the authentication/authorisation token provided by the `Client`. So, in the serialisation level, you will get basically *two parameters*, the token and the model, and accordingly will serialise appropriate properties or the instance as a whole.

When it comes to defining the *rules, roles and whatevers* per property for the model, it can be done in various ways depending on the available paradigms, i.e. depending on the language the `Service Layer` will be implemented. The definitions can be done heavily utilising [Annotations (Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) or [Decorators (Python)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators). For emitting specific properties, *Python* will come handy with its dynamic typing and hacky features, e.g. [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). In case of *Java*, you might end up encapsulating properties into a template class, say `AuthField<T>`.

**Summary**

Summing all up, I would suggest to put the instance and property authorization in front of the `API Layer` in the *stage of serialisation*. Thus basically, the roles/rules will be assigned in the model and the authorisation will be performed in the serialiser, being provided the model and token.

Answer (score 1):

Since a comment was added recently, I thought I'd update this post with my learnings since I originally asked the question...

Simply put, my original logic was flawed and I was trying to do too much in my business entities.  Following a CQRS approach helped make the solution clearer.

For state changes, the "write model" uses the business entity and a "command handler"/"domain service" performs authorization checks to make sure the user has the necessary permissions to update the requested object and, where applicable, change specific properties of that object.  I still debate whether the property-level checks belong inside the business entity methods or outside (in the handler/service).

In the case of the "read model", a "query handler"/"domain service" checks the resource- and instance-level authorization rules so only objects to which the user has access are returned.  The handler/service uses a mapper object that applies the property-level authorization rules to the data when constructing the DTO(s) to return.  In other words, the data access layer returns the "projection" (or view) regardless of authorization rules and the mapper ignores any properties to which the current user does not have access.

I dabbled with using dynamic query generation based on the list of fields to which the user has access but found that to be overkill in our case. But, in a more complex solution with larger, more complex entities, I can see that being more viable.